# Error PostgreSQL - restricción unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

He intentado crear tablas con el PostgreSQL y me había funcionado anteriormente pero ahora me da un error 82430: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «facturas».

Os paso el código que he formulado.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS tienda;

CREATE TABLE tienda.productos(
    
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar (40),
    precio numeric (6,2),
    cantidad_stock integer);
    
CREATE TABLE tienda.clientes(
    DNI char(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar (30),
    apellidos varchar (50),
    direccion varchar (100),
    fecha_nacimiento date);
    
CREATE TABLE tienda.facturas(
    id_factura serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    DNI_cliente char(9),
    fecha DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (DNI_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(DNI));

CREATE TABLE tienda.lineas_factura(
    id_lin_fact serial PRIMARY KEY,
    id_producto integer,
    id_fact integer,
    cantidad_vend integer,
    precio_vend numeric (6,2),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_fact) REFERENCES facturas(id_factura),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos(id));
```

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Tu escenario es sencillo, mira bien los nombres:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS tienda;

CREATE TABLE tienda.productos(
    
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar (40),
    precio numeric (6,2),
    cantidad_stock integer);
    
CREATE TABLE tienda.clientes(
    DNI char(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar (30),
    apellidos varchar (50),
    direccion varchar (100),
    fecha_nacimiento date);
    
CREATE TABLE tienda.facturas(
    id_factura serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    DNI_cliente char(9),
    fecha DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (DNI_cliente) REFERENCES tienda.clientes(DNI)); --Aqui es tienda.clientes

CREATE TABLE tienda.lineas_factura(
    id_lin_fact serial PRIMARY KEY,
    id_producto integer,
    id_fact integer,
    cantidad_vend integer,
    precio_vend numeric (6,2),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_fact) REFERENCES tienda.facturas(id_factura), --aqui es tienda.facturas
    FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES tienda.productos(id)); --aqui es tienda.productos
```